# Python: weird "NameError: name ... is not defined" in an 'exec' environment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was confident to have at least some basic understanding of Python's scope system. Now I get an error and unfortunately I'm not even able to write a good code snippet for reproduction so far. I tried to reproduce it in a new small project, but everything works as I expect there :-/

I can only describe what I do and hopefully somebody detects a pattern and can tell me what possibly goes wrong here.

At first there is a python file `x.py` which implements a class `X`.

In some other python file, there is the following string:

```
code="""
...
from x import X
...
class Y(X): # does not crash here, ...
    def __init__(self):
        X.__init__(self) # ... but here
        ...
foo=Y()
"""
```

You can assume that python is able to find the `x` module. At some place, I try to execute that:

```
exec(code, globals(), locals())
```

And now I get the `NameError`. It tells me that `X` is not defined when it tries to call it's constructor. It was obviously defined a few lines above.

If I modify `Y.__init__` with adding `from x import X` as first line, it works. But why the hell do I have to import it again there?

As already indicated, the actual code is more complex and does more things. In an unlucky case, my posting does not even show the part which actually leads to the problem. But maybe you have some general ideas, how one can get such a behaviour.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why call `X.__init__(self)` and not `X(self)`

Comment: I don't immediately see the problem, and it depends what else has happened to the global namespace, but usually you'd use `super(Y, self).__init__()` for such a case and avoid the whole issue.

Comment: ... well, just because I wasn't aware of that shortcut. But using it doesn't change anything about the error :(

Comment: Nothing changes the global namespace between the definition of Y and the instantiation which crashes. There really really is no code inbetween.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in what you have shown. what are the lines you are not showing?

Comment: What's in `Y.__init__.__globals__` and (`foo.__init__.__func__.__globals__`, if somehow those aren't the same thing)?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `exec(code, globals(), locals())` instead of just leaving the default?

Comment: At any rate, I can _guess_ what you might be doing wrong in your real code, but you're not doing it wrong in this example. In fact, there is nothing wrong in this example; if you remove the `...`s and create a trivial `x.py` with `class X: pass` and run it, it succeeds with no problems. So, please try to come up with an example that demonstrates your problem, or at least explain why you're using this pattern in the first place so we can try to make better guesses…

Comment: I avoided asking this until we'd hopefully gotten enough of the relevant information, but now I have to know: _why_ are you doing this? 99% of the time when people use exec, it's unnecessary, and it often adds new problems that wouldn't be there if you used Python's higher-level dynamic features instead. Of course there are some good uses for `exec` (the stdlib even uses it for `namedtuple` and very nicely explains why it's necessary), but there are a lot more bad uses.

Comment: Without sounding like a broken record, the way to get meaningful suggestions here is to post minimal code that demonstrate your problem. See [ask].

Comment: To the "why" question: I'm sure I would find enough people for every single design decision in all of my projects, who would judge them as ultimately poor. Although I'm not sure if it is always a good idea to hear too long what those people cite from some books, sometimes they are probably right. I use `exec` from time to time and I am really not sure if this is good or bad. I virtually always use that as some kind of very powerful config file parser, which allows code in config files and has a very fluid api for that particular task... Is that good or bad?

Comment: @boardrider: Thank you very much for your hint. However, I _got_ really meaningful suggestions ;)

Comment: Some reasons using `exec` that way is usually bad: (a) It means people can put arbitrary code in the config files and get it executed by your app, (b) it means you have to understand, and constantly think about, issues like fast locals vs. dict locals that don't arise otherwise (and the issue in this question, too), (c) it means you have code you can't debug/introspect/reflect on because it's present as text rather than code. Anyway, Python has very powerful dynamic and reflective features; many things that at first seem to require `exec` can actually be done in simpler and better ways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just a guess, because you haven't shown us enough code, and what you've shown us doesn't actually reproduce the problem, but…

If you're doing this `exec` inside a function, then `locals()` and `globals()` are going to be different. In which case the code will be executed as if it were inside a class definition. So, it'll be (sort of) as if you did this:

```
class _:
    from x import X
    class Y(X): # does not crash here, ...
        def __init__(self):
            X.__init__(self) # ... but here
    foo=Y()
del _
```

(I previously thought you'd have to *also* be doing something like `Y()` outside the `exec`, but [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979677/908494) convinced me that isn't necessary.)

If that's your problem, you may be able to fix it by just calling `exec(code, globals(), globals())` or `exec(code, locals(), locals())`. (Which one is appropriate, if either, depends on what you're actually trying to do, of course, which you haven't told us.)

Comment: I don't quite follow this... Why would `Y()` work in one scope and fail in a different scope, even though `Y` refers to the same class in both scopes?

Comment: I think the recommendation in the last paragraph is probably right, regardless.

Comment: Yeah, you were correct with your guesses ;) Great, thank you! I call `exec` in my real code from inside a function. In my test code, it was not in a function, so globals() and locals() maybe returned the same thing which leads to another behavior of `exec` (as you mentioned).

Comment: @abarnet Ah, OK, I see you've edited the part of the answer I wasn't following, so everything makes sense now.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff: Yeah, I upvoted user2357112's answer, but mine had already been accepted, so rather than delete it I corrected it.

Answer (score 8):

From the [`exec` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

There are good reasons for this, which I won't go into here.

Functions defined in a class definition don't look in the scope of the class definition for variable resolution. When you `exec` your `code`, it's actually executed like this:

```
class Dummy:
    from x import X
    ...
    class Y(X):
        def __init__(self):
            X.__init__(self)
            ...
    foo=Y()
```

That means this function:

```
def __init__(self):
    X.__init__(self)
```

doesn't see this variable:

```
from x import X
```

even though this bit:

```
class Y(X):
```

does see it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't quite right—if it were, his code as posted would raise, and it doesn't. That's why I think there has to be something else going on. My best guess, as in my answer, is that his actual code, unlike his example, is constructing `Y` instances _outside_ the `exec`, after the dummy class definition has finished executing and its scope has gone away and `X` is no longer available (or only available as a class attribute on an inaccessible class). But that's just a wild guess.

Comment: @abarnert: I'm not sure what you mean when you say it doesn't raise.

Comment: Take his code, remove the `...`s, create a `x.py` with `class X: pass`, and run it. No exception. Everything works. (The OP admitted from the start that his example isn't an MCVE because he's been unable to come up with a simple reproduction of the problem, and later edited it to make that even clearer: "In an unlucky case, my posting does not even show the part which actually leads to the problem.")

Comment: For that matter, just take your "as-if" code, remove the `...`s, and run it. It'll execute just fine, and you can verify that `Dummy.foo` is an instance of `__main__.Dummy.Y`. So, `Y.__init__`  is clearly able to see `X` at execution time.

Comment: @abarnert: I'm trying to run a simple example through ideone, but it's not loading. I don't have Python 3; could you link me an example?

Comment: @abarnert: Actually, never mind. I'm still having loading problems, but [it appears to have run and raised an error](http://ideone.com/ARzW0k). Did your tests behave differently?

Comment: @abarnert: Also, [here's the as-if code failing the same way](http://ideone.com/cTp5pc).

Comment: It's possible I did too many tests in the same session and ended up with a global `X` that was found after the class's `X` went away, in which case… yeah, you're right. Let me try a clean test.

Comment: OK, it looks like you're right. I'm not sure if that was the problem in my test, but there obviously was _some_ problem in my test…

Comment: Thank you, that is the correct answer... I really have learned something new :) I've accepted the other answer just because it came earlier.